# Can't parse links after a certain page using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, web-scraping

I've created a script using python to parse the links of different items traversing multiple pages. To parse the links from it's landing page, `get` requests also works, so I used `get` requests for the first page.

However, it is required to issue post requests with appropriate parameters to get the links from next pages. I did that as well. The script can now parse the links upto 11 pages. ***Trouble comes up when it gets after the 12 page and so on***. The script doesn't work anymore. I tried with different pages like 20,50,100,150. None worked out.

[Webpage link](https://www.brcdirectory.com/InternalSite//Siteresults.aspx?CountryId=0&CategoryId=49bd499b-bc70-4cac-9a29-0bd1f5422f6f&StandardId=972f3b26-5fbd-4f2c-9159-9a50a15a9dde)

I've tried with:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res_url = 'https://www.brcdirectory.com/InternalSite//Siteresults.aspx?'

params = {
    'CountryId': '0',
    'CategoryId': '49bd499b-bc70-4cac-9a29-0bd1f5422f6f',
    'StandardId': '972f3b26-5fbd-4f2c-9159-9a50a15a9dde'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    page = 11
    while True:
        print("**"*5,"trying with page:",page)
        req = s.get(res_url,params=params)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
        if page==1:
            for item_link in soup.select("h4 > a.colorBlue[href]"):
                print(item_link.get("href"))

        else:
            payload = {i['name']:i.get('value') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
            payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gv_Results'
            payload['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = f"{'Page$'}{page}"
            payload['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddl_SortValue'] = 'SiteName'

        res = s.post(res_url,params=params,data=payload)
        sauce = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        if not sauce.select("h4 > a.colorBlue[href]"):break
        for elem_link in sauce.select("h4 > a.colorBlue[href]"):
            print(elem_link.get("href"))

        page+=1
        time.sleep(3)
```

***How can I scrape links after 11 pages using requests?***

Comment: What you mean by "it doesn't work" ? Does the webserver returns some error? What happens?

Comment: Nope. No error is there. Just quits gracefully as i've defined this line `if not sauce.select("h4 > a.colorBlue[href]"):break`, otherwise the loop was going on without parsing anything.

Comment: Have you check the contents of the last page? It may give a clue. Also, check the status code of that last request and the headers returned.

Comment: At page `12` and later the Status is `500` and this is the headers `{'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/7.5', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Date': 'Sat, 12 Oct 2019 20:08:32 GMT', 'Content-Length': '104058'}`

Comment: 500 is Internal Server Error. Maybe the contents of the last page contains an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your scraping logic is correct but in your loop your are doing a GET + a POST each time whereas you should do a GET the first time then issue a POST for the next iterations (if you want 1 iteration = 1 page)

An example :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res_url = 'https://www.brcdirectory.com/InternalSite//Siteresults.aspx?'

params = {
    'CountryId': '0',
    'CategoryId': '49bd499b-bc70-4cac-9a29-0bd1f5422f6f',
    'StandardId': '972f3b26-5fbd-4f2c-9159-9a50a15a9dde'
}

max_page = 20

def extract(page, soup):
    for item_link in soup.select("h4 a.colorBlue"):
        print("for page {} - {}".format(page, item_link.get("href")))

def build_payload(page, soup):
    payload = {}
    for input_item in soup.select("input"):
        payload[input_item["name"]] = input_item["value"]
    payload["__EVENTTARGET"]="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gv_Results"
    payload["__EVENTARGUMENT"]="Page${}".format(page)
    payload["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddl_SortValue"] = "SiteName"
    return payload

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1, max_page):
        if (page > 1):
            req = s.post(res_url, params = params, data = build_payload(page, soup))
        else:
            req = s.get(res_url,params=params)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
        extract(page, soup)
```

Comment: My head is spinning to see the way you wrote your script. What I can't figure out is how this `build_payload(page, soup)` function worked out as it appears that sending requests and using BeautisulSoup are taking place at the same time.